# Do I have to source both ros2_galactic/install/setup.bash and /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash?

Tags: moveit, rosdep, apt, source, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TLDR:

Even with a source based install of ROS2, running rosdep will install libraries into `/opt/ros/galactic/`. To have all packages available in every terminal I open, do I have to source both `ros2_galactic/install/setup.bash` and `/opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash`?. If so, in which order?

---

Description:

I installed ros2_galactic **from source** following the instructions in the galactic tutorial.
I was next trying to install Moveit, and was coming across a CMake error indicating that the eigen_stl_containers library was missing.

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "eigen_stl_containers" with any of the following names:

    eigen_stl_containersConfig.cmake
    eigen_stl_containers-config.cmake
```

Although the rosdep command in the previous step should have downloaded eigen_stl_containers, I ran `sudo apt install ros-galactic-eigen-stl-containers`, but the output stated that I had the library already installed.

```
ros-galactic-eigen-stl-containers is already the newest version (1.0.0-3focal.20210507.020504).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

It turned out that the problem was I was only running `source ~/ros2_galactic/install/setup.bash`, but the eigen_stl_containers was installed through binaries so **I had to also run `source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash`**.

To have all packages available in every terminal I open, do I have to add both of those commands to `~/.bashrc`, and if so, **in which order**?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383624/do-i-have-to-source-both-ros2_galactic/install/setup.bash-and-/opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash?/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2021-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any packages you want to use will need to exist on paths on the various ROS environment variables (e.g. `PATH`, `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH`, etc). The order in which you source these should be determined by what you want to have priority.

Environment variable additions are *prepended* so if you had both source and binary installations of a given package, *priority* would be given to the one you sourced the *most recently*. In your case, you probably want to prioritize the source installation, so you would probably want to:

```
source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash
source ~/ros2_galactic/install/setup.bash
```

You can add these two lines to the end of your `.bashrc` if you don't want to manually source both paths every time you open a new terminal.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1